Unable to select resolution shown in xrandr
I have two monitors connected through a docking station. Up until recently both monitors worked. I now have a new docking station and one of the monitors will not allow me to select a resolution above 1024x768. Both allow for up to 3840x2160. Both monitors are the same model, both docking stations connected via USB-C. The monitors connect to the docking station via HDMI cables.
When I run xrandr I get the following (both monitors seem to have the same resolutions available):
DP-1-1 connected 2048x1536+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     30.00    29.97    29.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     30.00*   29.97    29.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-1-1 is the monitor I am having an issue with. When I run commands such as xrandr --output DP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --rate 30 I get the following error xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed (running this same command with DP-1-2 causes no errors).
When I run cvt -r 3840 2160 it produces the following:
# 3840x2160 59.97 Hz (CVT 8.29M9-R) hsync: 133.25 kHz; pclk: 533.00 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160R"  533.00  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync

I have tried adding this as a new mode for both monitors and then setting them to use that mode however I still get the xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed error.
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160R" 533.00 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1-1 "3840x2160R"
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160R
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed

Is there a way to tell xrandr to treat these displays identically and just extend them?
xrandr verbose output:
DP-1-1 connected 2048x1536+3840+0 (0x80) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  2219473
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 2 0
    Transform:  2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: bilinear
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff00220ed53601010101
        0c210103803c22782eee95a3544c9926
        0f5054a10800d1c0a9c0a940d100b300
        9500810081801acb003cf0703e800820
        350055502100001a000000fd001d3c1c
        873c000a202020202020000000fc0048
        50205a32376b2047330a2020000000ff
        00434e34333132314731540a202001d0
        020333b15110100403021f1312115f05
        1407061615016b030c001000383c2000
        200167d85dc401788003e20f00e2006b
        e20e61a36600a0f0701f803020350055
        502100001a023a801871382d40582c45
        0055502100001e283c80a070b0234030
        20360055502100001a565e00a0a0a029
        503020350055502100001a00000000ea
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: -26997632 0 1461765 0 9823659 -2147483648 1354350 -2147483648 4555181 1 6089007 0 661164 -2147483648 3539183 -2147483648 
        17386285 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 128 
        supported: 128
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  3840x2160 (0x6f) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x70) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0x71) 262.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock  65.69KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2191           clock  29.98Hz
  2560x1440 (0x72) 241.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1200 (0x73) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x74) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x75) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x76) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x1200 (0x77) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x78) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x900 (0x79) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x7a) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x7b) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x800 (0x7c) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1280x720 (0x7d) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x7e) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x7f) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x80) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x81) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x82) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x83) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x84) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x85) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x86) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x87) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
  3840x2160R (0x9ac) 533.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2222           clock  59.97Hz
DP-1-2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0x6f) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  2219473
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 2 0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff00220ed53601010101
        0c210103803c22782eee95a3544c9926
        0f5054a10800d1c0a9c0a940d100b300
        9500810081801acb003cf0703e800820
        350055502100001a000000fd001d3c1c
        873c000a202020202020000000fc0048
        50205a32376b2047330a2020000000ff
        00434e34333132314734370a202001ea
        020333b15110100403021f1312115f05
        1407061615016b030c001000383c2000
        200167d85dc401788003e20f00e2006b
        e20e61a36600a0f0701f803020350055
        502100001a023a801871382d40582c45
        0055502100001e283c80a070b0234030
        20360055502100001a565e00a0a0a029
        503020350055502100001a00000000ea
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CTM: -26997632 0 1461765 0 9823659 -2147483648 1354350 -2147483648 4555181 1 6089007 0 661164 -2147483648 3539183 -2147483648 
        17386285 1 
    CONNECTOR_ID: 130 
        supported: 130
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  3840x2160 (0x6f) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x70) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0x71) 262.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock  65.69KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2191           clock  29.98Hz
  2560x1440 (0x72) 241.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1200 (0x73) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x74) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x75) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x76) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x1200 (0x77) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x78) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x900 (0x79) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1704 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x1024 (0x7a) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x7b) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x800 (0x7c) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1280x720 (0x7d) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x7e) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x7f) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x80) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x81) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x82) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x83) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x84) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x85) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x86) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x87) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
  3840x2160R (0x9ac) 533.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2222           clock  59.97Hz

When I swap the ports each HDMI cable is plugged into on the docking station the problem swaps from monitor to the other (so it stays on the same port regardless of which monitor is connected) and when I try the docking station with a windows laptop both displays work fine so I am assuming it is something with how it is configured.
